# how to add api keys in vanilla javascript with .env file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how to add **config.env** api key file in app.js

this file name config.env:
example:
 API_KEY ="123456";

Comment: is this a nodejs application? is this frontend? do you use any bundler if its a frontend application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.env` file in the root of your project with the following content:

```
API_KEY=123456
```

in your `app.js`:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
...

// Use the API_KEY
const client = new ApiClient(process.env.API_KEY);
```

Comment: hide api for public/app,js not in a server.js file